# need to store data of dynamic form fields values using angular node js

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js

Am having a 2 static input fields based on that field user can add some more fields which have item name, item description, item count,and 2 combo boxes user can add any number of fields by clicking add fields no I need to store the 2 static input field value in one mysql table and dynamic fields value in another mysql table,I have written the myswl insert query in node js but the both static and dynamic fields values are not storing instead it stores undefined, I will post my node,html,angular js code below please do correct me

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="okay.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="testApp">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<form name="frm" class="form-inline" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="string" name="cat_name" class="form-control" ng-model="choices.cat_name" placeholder="Enter Category Name" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="cat_desc" class="form-control" ng-model="choices.cat_desc" placeholder="Enter Your Description" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    No of Item Count<input type="disable" class="form-control"  name="count" ng-disabled="true" ng-model="choices.length">
  </div>
  <br>
  <fieldset data-ng-repeat="choice in choices track by $index" >
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" ng-model="choice.itemName" class="form-control" name="item_name" placeholder="Category Item Name" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" ng-model="choice.itemDesc" class="form-control" name="item_desc" placeholder="Category Description" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/" required>
      </div>
<div class="form-group">
      <input type="number" ng-model="choice.itemView" class="form-control" name="item_count" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]/" placeholder="Category Item View Count" required>
      <p class="help-block" ng-show="frm.item_count.$error.pattern">numbers only allowed</p>
     State:<select id="country" ng-model="choice.states" name="state" ng-options="country for (country, states) in countries">
    </div>
      <div class="form-group"> 
    <option value=''>Choose</option>
        </select> City:
        <select id="state" ng-disabled="!choice.states" name="city" ng-model="one">
            <option value="">Choose</option>
            <option ng-repeat="state in choice.states" value="{{state.id}}">{{state.city}}</option>
        </select>
     </div>
    <button ng-click="removeChoice()" class="remove btn btn-danger" >close</button>
  </fieldset>
  <br>
  <button class="addfields btn btn-success" ng-click="addNewChoice()" ng-disabled="!frm.cat_name.$dirty||!frm.cat_desc.$dirty||frm.cat_desc.$invalid||frm.cat_name.$inavalid">Add fields</button>
 <button class="addfields btn btn-success" ng-disabled="!frm.cat_name.$dirty||!frm.cat_desc.$dirty||frm.cat_desc.$invalid||frm.cat_name.$inavalid||!frm.item_name.$dirty||frm.item_name.$invalid||!frm.item_desc.$dirty||frm.item_desc.$invalid||!frm.item_count.$dirty||frm.item_count.$invalid||!frm.state.$dirty||!frm.city.$dirty" ng-click="submit()">Save</button>
  <span class="help-block" style="color:red" ng-show="frm.cat_desc.$error.pattern">ERROR:<BR/>text only allowed</span >
  <span class="help-block" style="color:red" ng-show="frm.item_desc.$error.pattern">ERROR:<BR/>text only allowed</span >  
  <span class="help-block" style="color:red" ng-show="frm.cat_name.$error.pattern">ERROR:<BR/>text only allowed</span >
  <span class="help-block" style="color:red" ng-show="frm.item_name.$error.pattern">ERROR:<BR/>text only allowed</span >
 </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Angular (okay)

```
var app=angular.module('testApp', []);
  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
  $scope.choices = [{}];
  var newItemNo;
  $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
    newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
    $scope.choices.push({'id':'choice'+newItemNo});

}
  $scope.no=newItemNo;
  $scope.removeChoice = function() {
    $scope.choices.splice(this.$index,1);
  };

$scope.submit=function(category){
$http({method:"post",url:"http://localhost:3000/insert",data:category})
 .then(function(data){
                /* Success callback */
            alert("Data hase been entered!");
                // console.log("success");
            },function(err){
                /* Failure callback */
           alert("Something went wrong!");
            });
}

     $scope.countries = {
         'Andhra': [{
             'id': '01',
             'city': "Guntur"
         }, {
             'id': '02',
             'city': "Hyderabad"
         }],
             'Tamilnadu': [{
             'id': '03',
             'city': "CBE"
         }, {
             'id': '04',
             'dep': "Trichy"
         }]
     };
});
```

Node (server)

```
var mysql=require('mysql');
var http=require('http');
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var path=require('path');
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
var bodyparser=require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyparser.json());       
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true})); 
var myconnection = mysql.createConnection({
host : "localhost",

user : "root",

password : "",

database : "siva"
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + ""));
var uqid= uuid.v1();
var it_id=uuid.v4();
var tt=1;
var status="active";
app.post("/insert",function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    /* TODO: Now just check that your drive function is correct, SQL is correct and whether what arguements passed to SQL callback is correct */
    myconnection.query('Insert into cate_tbl (cat_id,cat_name,cat_desc,cat_view_count,cat_status) VALUES ("'+uqid+'","'+req.body.cat_name+'","'+req.body.cat_desc+'","'+tt+'","'+status+'")',function(err, results, fields) {

        if (err) {console.log("DB Error"+err); res.send("add failed"+err);}
        else res.send("add success");
    });
      myconnection.query('Insert into cate_item (cat_it_id,cat_it_name,cat_pid,cat_it_count,cat_it_desc,cat_it_status) VALUES ("'+it_id+'","'+req.body.itemName+'","'+uqid+'","'+tt+'","'+req.body.itemDesc+'","'+status+'")',function(err, results, fields) {
        //if (err) throw err;
        if (err) {console.log("DB Error"+err); res.send("add failed"+err);}
        else res.send("add success");
    });
});
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile("index.html");
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("It's Started on PORT 3000");
})
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Try using some periods, and clearly state what the problem is.

Comment: am having a add fields button to add some dynamic fields, I need to store that value in db how I can do that